# All the cowards complain

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> A bird, a plane? I am more like the rain
>   "Stupid", "insane", all the cowards complain
>   Near the end of the run, I slowed my pace
>   And thence ended the fun, and my heart's race
>
> What am I?

No offense for using the word "coward", just a figure of speech.

Comment: Nice rhyming on this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be

> a parachutist.

- *A bird, a plane? I am more like the rain*

  > You move through the sky, but mainly downwards, like a raindrop.
- *"Stupid", "insane", all the cowards complain*

  > Some non-parachutists might use these terms to describe your sport.
- *Near the end of the run, I slowed my pace*

  > As you approach the ground for landing, the parachute slows you down.
- *And thence ended the fun, and my heart's race*

  > The jump is over, and the adrenaline rush subsides (so your heart rate decreases).

Comment: A Glider would also fit this logic.

Comment: Ahh.. This is better. +1

Comment: How would the glider be rain-like, @Chris ?

Comment: Generally descending.

Comment: More than a bird, I suppose; OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> **A Nomad**

A bird, a plane? I am more like the rain

> Like rain, they travel and fall upon places to places

"Stupid", "insane", all the cowards complain

> People often call them by these names.

Near the end of the run, I slowed my pace

> They settle down and end their long run once they find a final destination.

And thence ended the fun, and my heart's race

> Travelling is what they are called for. Stopping that leads to an end of fun for them and hence stops their race to stay a Nomad.